# VBA loop macro displays no errors, but show no results after start

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I am trying to come up with user form in which data is entered and after button press automatically moved to table.

My user form consist from two option buttons (to help differentiate where to put entered data), and two text boxes: one to enter criteria and other to enter date, which have to be put into cells meeting criteria. So far I came up to this code:

```
Private Sub UzdarytiCB_Click() 

Dim i As Long
   'setting conditions for first option button selection     
If OptionButton1 = True And Condition_TextBox <> "" _
   'with other subs I have made default text in texbox which is shown until clicked
   'this line should stop macro from starting if no text is entered and default text left
   And Condition_TB <> "Enter Application ID" Then

      ' I want macro to loop throught all the table until it finds a match
      For i = 3 To Range("Table1").Rows.Count

 'Conditions to finding a match. Cell in column D should say "Remarks" and entered value should match cell in column A
           If Condition_TB = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value _
           And Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value = "Remarks" Then
'If conditions are met I want macro to change column D cell value to "done" and write date from second texbox to cell in column N
               Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "N").Value = Condition_TB
               Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value = "Done"
               'Since there will be no more mach I want to stop the loop
               Exit For
               End If
            Next i

    ' Second option button similar to first, but it should not stop after first match
    ElseIf  OptionButton2 = True And Condition_TextBox <> "" _
            And Condition_TB <> "Enter Application ID" _
            And Condition_TB <> "Enter item number" Then

               For i = 3 To Range("Table1").Rows.Count
                   If Condition_TB = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "P").Value _
                   And Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value = "Make a call" Then
                       Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "L").Value = DataTB
                       Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value = "Call made"
                       End If
                    Next i
    End If                   
  End Sub
```

Whole code shows no errors so far, but then clicked and data is entered nothing happens. 
Since I am beginner whole code could be inherently wrong, please help me find a mistake or get in to the right track.

Comment: Where's the **Then** in the first If statement?

Comment: Sorry, I  accidentally dropped it then edited code to look clear in the post, in original file **Then** is in place. I edited my post.

Comment: So Condition_TB  can be either "Enter Application ID" or "Enter item number"?

Comment: Yes, is is default text shown in Condition_TB until it is clicked and different text is entered. If it "Enter Application ID" or "Enter item number" depends on option button selection.  Both of them are generated by another macro, but I do not think it interferes with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying Dylan L debugging method, I pinpointed problem to loop's IF. Turns out `If Condition_TB = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "P").Value` should be `If Condition_TB.Text = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "P").Value`

Also I encountered problem that for some reason loop ignored first 4 cells even if they meet conditions. to fix that i rearranged my code and separated options IF's to two different routines also `For i = 3 To Range("Table1").Rows.Count` changed to `For i = 1 To Range("Table1").Rows.Count`

I do not know which part helped, but final result seems to work. I am posting final code so maybe somebody can use it.

Also if anybody can offer some improvements or have some criticism I will gladly accept it since I am beginner and learning on the way.

```
Private Sub UzdarytiCB_Click()

Dim i As Long
i = 1


  If OptionButton1 = True And Number_TextBox <> "" _
     And Number_TextBox <> "Enter application ID" _
     And Number_TextBox <> "Enter item ID" Then

         For i = 1 To Range("Table1").Rows.Count
             If Number_TextBox.Text = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "P").Value _
                And Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value = "Make a call" Then
                    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "L").Value = DataTB
                    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value = "Call made"
                End If
              Next i
    End If

If OptionButton2 = True And Number_TextBox <> "" _
    And Number_TextBox <> "Enter application ID" _
    And Number_TextBox <> "Enter item ID" Then

     For i = 1 To Range("Table1").Rows.Count
            If Number_TextBox.Text = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value _
                And Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value = "Remarks" Then
               Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "N").Value = DataTB
               Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value = "Done"
               End If
            Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're very close on this one!

The first few things I'm noticing thay may be causing problems are your IF conditions.

Try these changes to see if you're getting the results you want:

Change:

```
If OptionButton1 = True And Condition_TextBox <> "" Then
```

To

```
If OptionButton1 = True And Condition_TextBox.value <> "" Then
```

Anywhere that the user enters a value for a userform object, and you're checking the value of the user defined input add ".value" after the object to check the user input.

Keep in mind that your optionsbuttons are fine as they are. These options buttons don't need a ".value" property when checking if True, or False.

***Debugging tip for the future:***

As a additional side note to help you debug your code in the future you can add triggers after if statements that notify you if the conditions were met. If the trigger doesn't show then you know where your problem is.

For example:

You can add the following immediately after your conditions:

```
MsgBox("Condition 1 was met!")
```

or

```
Debug.Print("Condition 1 was met!")
```

Lets see where that gets you. If you have more questions I'm happy to help!

Comment: I have used your advice with MsgBox. I was able to pinpoint that problem is in the `For i = 1 To Range("Table1").Rows.Count
            If Condition_TB = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value _
            And Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value = "Remarks" Then` 
It is strange because `For i = 3 To Range("Table1").Rows.Count
                   If Condition_TB = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "P").Value _
                   And Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value = "Make a call" Then` seems to work now (I separated it to another If)